# Get the duplicate rows with the number of occurrence in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need to list all the duplicate IDs with the number of occurrence of each ID in a single MYSQL query.

```
 ID
____
 1
 1
 2
 3
 4
 4
 4
 5
 5
 6
 7
```

**Output** must be:

```
ID | Occurrence
_______________
 1 | 2
 4 | 3
 5 | 2
```

Comment: select ID,count(*) from table_name group by ID having count(*)>1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS Occcurrence
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply by using [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) clause and [Count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) function

```
select 
    Id, count(id) as Occurance
from
    tableName
group by id
having Occurance > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql GROUP BY

```
select ID,count(*) from table_name group by ID having count(*) > 1
```